# Filtering dates by validity in QGIS 3.14

Tags: qgis, expression, filter, date

I have a WFS data, which I'm trying to filter by `DATE`. I'm using query builder. I need to filter valid dates which are max three years older than current date. I can do it if I calculate three years my self, like `"DATE" >= '2018-05-10T00:00:00.000'`. Is there any expression that calculates that automatically every day, and shows only features that are valid?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the value `now()` that returns the current date/time and subtract from it the value of your `DATE` field. Convert that to years with the function `year()`. If the result is greater than three, you want to skip it - see on the screenshot where I used the expression `3 > year (now() - "DATE" )` to select the DATES that are less than 3 years old.

Use a [virtual field](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=virtual%20field#creating-a-virtual-field) to always update the value.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for yor advice. I had troubles  and I didn't succeed, maybe too much for my skills, but I heard a another way to try.  Idea is to use rule based symbology with filter year( now() ) -  "DATE" <=3 and that seems to work.